# DNS, verify domain DKIM

Tags: dns, dkim, spf

I have 3 domains: `example.com`, `example2.com` and `s1.example.com`

These 3 domains have their own servers

When I sending mails any of them DKIM, SPF and DMARC are PASS but when I send mail form s1.example.com as info@example.com or info@example2.com DKIM is not pass.

SPF is easy for me to pass but DKIM is real problem for me.

s1.example.com is the SMTP server and I want to send mails only from here.
Please tell me some advice.

I've been searching the whole day in Google about this but no luck :).

I need some help from you.

Comment: The question is not really clear maybe because of different languages. What do you mean with "When I sending mails any of them DKIM, SPF and DMARC are PASS but when I send mail form s1.example.com as info@example.com or info@example2.com DKIM is not pass." ? Does it mean that it works for example.com but not for the other two?

Comment: sorry for my english. direct mails when i use roundcube or php to send mails from example.com as info@example.com i mean from mail is info@example.com everything is good. when i show header for example on my gmail DKIM, SPF AND DMARC is PASS. But when i try to send mails from s1.example.com as info@example.com - info@example.com is from mail only SPF is PASS. i want to use s1.eaxmple.com as SMTP server and send mails only from this server but i need to send mails as  info@example.com and also info@example2.com